# Как обратиться к элементу массива на ассемблере(fasm)

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, fasm

Каков аналог записи array[i] (i-й элемент массива array) в фасме? Например мне нужно сравнить первый элемент массива с нулём, как будет выглядеть такая запись?

Comment: Зависит от размера элемента в массиве. Например, если четырехбайтные числа, то что-то типа `mov eax, [array+esi*4]`

Comment: Я уже по учебнику разобрался, но всё же, спасибо за ответ)